# Android AR Sceneform device orientation change

Tags: android, arcore, android-orientation, sceneform, android-configchanges

I'm working on an app that has a Single Activity and a fullscreen Fragment in that activity that uses AR Core and inherits from Sceneform. What is a good strategy for handling orientation with AR elements? It seems that most Google produced applications that user AR (Camera Playground, Maps, Arts and Culture) lock the view to portrait when in an AR session. However, we want users to be able to interact with the view when tilted to landscape as well. That would be fine to still have it locked to portrait and the user could just tilt their phone except for the issue with Android 10 gesture navigations. If a user orients their phone in landscape (while the activity is locked to portrait), a swipe from the top of the screen (which would appear to bring up the status bar) would send an onBackPressed() which would be a big UX issue.

Have others faced this issue before? Is it possible to programmatically remove the gesture navigations? Or move them without a full config change?